# OnClick event not working in map function react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, onclick, array.prototype.map

I am unsure why I cannot use onClick on this within map function???I am getting the data from useSelector in my redux file. Clicking the TestComponent does nothing it seems can't even console log anything. I took out some irrelevant code to see easier. MY actual goa lis to pass the index in the TestComponent to a reducer method. But first I just want to console something at least.

```
import React from "react";
import CourseListItem from "../components/CourseListItem";
import styles from "./CourseList.module.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { slideActions } from "../store/index";

export default function CourseList() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const totalSlides = useSelector((state) => state.slide.SlideData.length);
  const currentSlide = useSelector((state) => state.slide.currentSlide);

  const SlideData = useSelector((state) => state.slide.SlideData);
  const list = SlideData.map((item, index) => (
    <CourseListItem key={index} slideNumber={index} title={item.title} onClick={console.log("hello")} />
  ));

  const currentSlideContent = useSelector((state) => {
    //if array item is defined return its title//
    if (state.slide.SlideData[currentSlide]) {
      return state.slide.SlideData[currentSlide].title;
    }
  });

  const nextSlideHandler = () => {
    dispatch(slideActions.goNextSlide());
  };
  const prevSlideHandler = () => {
    dispatch(slideActions.goPrevSlide());
  };
  const goToSlideHandler = (param) => {
    dispatch(slideActions.goToSlide(param));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div>
          <h2>Total Slides: {totalSlides}</h2>
          <h2>Current Slide: {currentSlide}</h2>
          <button onClick={nextSlideHandler}>Next Slide</button>
          <button onClick={prevSlideHandler}>Prev Slide</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>List</h1>
          {list}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I edited this to include all my code from this file. I apologize.

Comment: Any errors in the console when you click on your `TestComponent`?

Comment: what is that TestComponent ? replace that for <p key={index}>{item.title}</p> to see if you got somting right

Comment: You have not created any class or function-based component. Try to make this component function-based and call it. Then it will works. Also you have not imported TestComponent.

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL This is not the way we work with react. He has to import TestComponent before using in map. Also make this whole component class based or functional.

Comment: @SulemanAhmad you are right, he missed the import, so i was thinking that was a typing error that testcomponent...thats why i asked what was that...

Comment: no errors unfortunately, and I could probably make that component just a div for now. Sry meant to fix that.

Comment: hopefully this helps, on run as is, I get 3 hellos that print to the console. there are 3 objects in my slidedata file. Should I post that to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why. First I wasnt writing my onClick right, secondly I didnt pass the onClick down to the component via props which was the main thing.

```
fix one
1) onClick={() => {console.log("hello");}}

fix two in CourseListItem.js
2)
 <div onClick={props.onClick}>
        //stuff
 </div>
```

I asked this question poorly, an didn't include all my code, lesson learned!

Answer (score 1):

You have not created any class or **function-based** component. Try to make this function-based component as you are using Hooks and call it. Then it will work. Also, you have not **imported** TestComponent. Do like this and it will work hopefully:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./CourseList.module.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { slideActions } from "../store/index";
import {TestComponent} from 'TestComponent'; //Import from your project this is hint


export const Tester = () => { // Make it functional like this

//get slide data//
const SlideData = useSelector((state) => state.slide.SlideData);

//map data
const list = SlideData.map((item, index) => (
    <TestComponent key={index} slideNumber={index} title={item.title} onClick={()=>console.log("hello")} />
  ));

//render components
return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}
        <div>
          <h1>List</h1>
          {list}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
  } //Ends here
```

Now call this **Tester Component** from your project and check console after **onClick**.

Answer (score 1):

Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a functional component

```
import styles from "./CourseList.module.css";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { slideActions } from "../store/index";

//map data
const list = SlideData.map((item, index) => (
    <TestComponent key={index} slideNumber={index} title={item.title} onClick={()=>console.log("hello")} />
  ));

const componentName = () => {
//get slide data//
const SlideData = useSelector((state) => state.slide.SlideData);

 return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div>
          <h1>List</h1>
          {list}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I apologize I didnt include all the code, i edited it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using reactslick npm and need to pass arguments through function just call like this

```
data.map(val=>
<div onClick={()=>handleplay(val)} >slide</div>
)
```